# Modify WordPress loop after it has been run

Tags: posts, loop, query-posts

I am trying to build a category page that displays **8 posts** from the category, but when the user clicks on "Read More" (which does an Ajax request and displays more posts), I would like the loop to then display **9 posts**.

Here is my current code:

```
  <?php
      // Variables
      $posts_per_page = 8;
      $loopCount;

      // Loop arguments
      $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'paged'          => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
      );

      // The Loop
      query_posts($args);
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>

      <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php $loopCount++; ?>

    <?php
      if ($loopCount == 8) {
        $posts_per_page = 9;
      }
    ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The code runs fine, however, there are still 8 posts being displayed when the page is loaded, and when the "Read More" button is clicked.

How can I modify the loop after it displays 8 posts to then display 9?

Comment: `$posts_per_page` is just a number value, why would changing it to 9 modify a database query and loop which have already ran in the past?

Answer (score 0):

First:

- Indent your code consistently, your code editor should do this automatically, if it doesn't, you should change, I can recommend Sublime Text as a free option, but there are hundreds of others
- Don't spam PHP tags, `<?php echo 'you'; ?><?php echo ' dont '; ?><?php echo 'need ';?><?php echo 'this'; ?>`, when `<?php echo 'you can just open tags once and close them when your done?';?>`
- **Never** use `query_posts`. If I was your employer I would have fired you for such a thing. Whoever taught you to use it, they did you a disservice. To fetch posts in WordPress, use `WP_Query` or `get_posts`, to modify a query, use the `pre_get_posts` filter. Remember to call `wp_reset_postdata` afterwards to clean up
- Pick a style and stick to it, you either `if() {}` or `if(): endif;`, don't mix the 2 types, it just makes life difficult and your code difficult to read

As for your issue, just print out 9 posts. Wrap the 9th post in a div that's hidden by default and toggle it's visibility with javascript when you press a button.